# Execute blade tags in textarea

Tags: html, laravel

I am setting up a simple CMS and I am using a Textarea (Froala to be exact) to render the HTML content of each page that's generated via database. The textarea can display the html with no problems. However, the blade template isn't executing. It's just in plain text. How can I make sure blade executes correctly? I need it mainly for links.

For an example. I have a form element written in blade:

```
{{ Form::text('name')}}
```

It should display like so on my page:

```
<input name="name" type="text">
```

However, it's just displaying like this:

```
{{ Form::text('name')}}
```

EDIT: here is my pages.blade.php file if they may help with figuring it out.

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('main_content')
<section class="mainContent">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 title="{{ $pages->title }}">{{ $pages->title }}</h1>
        {{ $pages->body }}
    </div>
</section>
@stop
```

Comment: Where is `{{ Form::text('name')}}` in your blade file??? Or is it coming from database in `$pages->body`?

Comment: That was just an example. But yes, it would be coming from the database and `$pages->body` would be displaying it

Comment: As I understand it (and I've tested the theory), the "blading" happens before the incorporation of data.  Regular HTML tags (`<input name="name" type="text">`) will be parsed as HTML, but your Blade structures arrive too late to be built into the page... Can you use regular HTML?

Comment: Yeah, 99% it shouldn't be an issue. I was just mainly wanting it for the absolute links

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box way to do that. Blade templates are compiled only from files.

But you can take look at

- [Flynsarmy/laravel-db-blade-compiler](https://github.com/Flynsarmy/laravel-db-blade-compiler) if you want to compile Blade from Eloquent model

or

- [TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler](https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler) if you want to compile Blade from strings.